# POST value to input box and activate submit button using cURL

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I wanted to post value to website input search box and activate submit button as we do it manually.

Is it possible to pass value using `cURL` library in `php.`

Now I am able to do fetch data using website search query like

```
https://www.example.com/search.aspx?q=productnumber
```

but I wanted to do this using search function..

Suppose I want to post value to this input box and activate submit button to search.

```
<div>
    <input type="search" class="text js-focus" id="searchterm_sh">
    <button class="submit blue-button border" type="submit" id="searchbutton_sh">Search</button>
</div>
```

My current code which fetch data from absolute query

like - `https://www.example.com/search.aspx?q=productnumber`
But every website not provide this kind of url means we can change `productnumber` only. So for this I need to pass value to search box.

```
$ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $output = curl_exec ($ch); 
    curl_close ($ch); 
    var_dump($output);
```

### **Update**

using this `curl http://www.universalapplianceparts.com/search.aspx?find=w10130694` I am getting expected output in terminal I want to do this in php.

[Sample Website](http://www.partselect.com/)

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should post an example of what you've tried and what form you're trying to access. You can definitely make POST requests with curl.

Comment: Hi, Please check updated question